# C# setting property to interface class using dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface, ninject

I have the following `class` that implements **dependency injection** for `ISecurityRepository`:

```
public class SecurityService : BaseService
    {
        ISecurityRepository _securityRepo = null;

        public SecurityService(ISecurityRepository securityRepo)
        {
            _securityRepo = securityRepo;
        }
}
```

Then I have the `SecurityRepository` class as follows:

```
public class SecurityRepository : BaseRepository, ISecurityRepository
    {
        public bool ValidateLogin(string userName, string password)
        {
            return true;
        }
}
```

Then `BaseRepository` class:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository
    {

        private string _customString = null;
        public string CustomString{
            get {
                return _customString ;
            }
            set
            {
                value = _customString ;
            }
        }
}
```

> What I need is to set **CustomString** on `BaseRepository` class value from `SecurityService` class. Something maybe like this:

```
public class SecurityService : BaseService
        {
            ISecurityRepository _securityRepo = null;

            public SecurityService(ISecurityRepository securityRepo)
            {
                _securityRepo = securityRepo;

                // something like this or better way  
                _securityRepo.CustomString = "ABCD";
            }
    }
```

The idea is that within `SecurityRepository` class I can access `CustomString` value.

Comment: You will need to add `CustomString` to the `ISecurityRepository` interface.

Comment: So every Interface will need to have that added? What about having a common interface for all the interfaces? Is that possible?

Comment: Having a common interface is possible. All repository interfaces will inherit from it.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].